# Data-Filter Overriding Data-Search Attribute

Tags: datatables

Using DataTables, I am witnessing a reproduceable issue where the value of the data-filter html attribute is overriding the searchability of the data-search html attribute.

```
<td data-search="Jared Next" data-order="Jared Next" data-filter="Full-Time DM">
  <div class="mb-2">
    Jared Next
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2 text-muted small" title="Number of total deals posted by DM">
    Posted: 294
  </div>
</td>
```

When searching by "jared" the row does not appear.

When searching by "full-time dm" the row does appear.

Worth mentioning that the filter works as expected:

I apologize if I've not provided enough code to re-create the issue or if DataTables experts want the whole table.

I can easily provide it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-search` and `data-filter` attributes are synonyms, in DataTables.

See [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) for details.

You should use one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Also, from the same doc link as above, in case it is relevant: Make sure the attributes are used consistently for every cell in a column:

> *In order for the HTML 5 data-* attribute detection and processing to work correctly, all cells in a column must have the same attribute available.*

Comment: This blows my mind. I'm left feeling hurt that the DataTables community couldn't imagine a usecase where a column would need a filtered value different from a searchable value. I do love DataTables so I will try not to complain too much about this.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The sometimes-separate, but also sometimes-overlapping uses of "filter" and "search" in DataTables teminology & functionality is tricky.